# jquery - get part of path?

Tags: jquery, substring

I have a url that looks like this : http://mysite.com/1/2/Simpson and I want to create a variable that contains just Simpson...

Not sure how to do it here...

I have:

var myvar = window.location.pathname

and have tried something using substring, but can't seem to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work, but you might as well use the `string` window.location.href, not the `object` window.location (which contains many different objects within it):

```
var dirs = window.location.href.split( '/' );
```

however, there is a window.location.pathname that you could split, too.  it just depends on if you want the part in front of the first "/" to be in the arrays as well (http://mysite.com).

```
var dirs = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```