# Javascript - If url contains X, ignore script, else, run script

Tags: javascript, url

I'm rather new to Javascript and I can't seem to get a script to run/not run on certain pages.

I have this script on my main page to hide and unhide content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".hidden").hide();
$(".show").html("[+]");
$(".show").click(function() {
    if (this.className.indexOf('clicked') != -1 ) {
        $(this).prev().slideUp(0);
        $(this).removeClass('clicked')
        $(this).html("[+]");
        }
        else {
        $(this).addClass('clicked')
        $(this).prev().slideDown(0);
        $(this).html("[–]");
        }
    });
});
```

I need some coding like this:

if url contains "/post/" then ignore script
else run script

It should be a simple fix. I just can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The `if` you're looking for is:

```
if (window.location.indexOf('/post/') == -1){
    // don't run, the '/post/' string wasn't found
}
else {
    // run
}
```

`indexOf()` returns `-1` if the string wasn't found, else it returns the index in the string where the first character of the string is found.

The above rewritten with added common sense provided by Jason (in comments, below):

```
if (window.location.indexOf('/post/') > -1){
    // run, the '/post/' string was found
}
```

Comment: I would write this as `if (window.location.indexOf('/post/') >= 0){ // code to run here }` to avoid the (confusing) empty if block.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669486/4107296),

> `window.location` is an object, not a string, and so it doesn't have an
>   `indexOf` function.

... So `window.location.indexOf()` will never work.

However, as guided by the same answer, you could convert the URL to a string with `window.location.href` to then perform searches. Or you could access parts of the URL, like this:

`if (window.location.pathname === '/about/faculty/'){` ... `}`  for an exact match

or

`window.location.pathname.split( '/' )` to get parts of the url, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931716/4107296).