# window.location.indexOf not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, alert, indexof

Below is what I have.

```
var myString = "http://localhost:8888/www.smart-kw.com/";
alert(myString.indexOf("localhost"));
```

This give me alert... however if I change `var myString = "http://localhost:8888/www.smart-kw.com/";` to `var myString = window.location;`, it won't work (I don't get alert).

```
var myString = window.location;
alert(myString.indexOf("localhost"));
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Okay, I will take care of that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) is an accessor property, and getting its value gives you an object, not a string, and so it doesn't have an `indexOf` function. (It's perfectly understandable that people sometimes think it's a string, since when you *set* its value, the accessor property's setter accepts a string; that is, `window.location = "some url";` actually works. But when you *get* it, you don't get a string.)

You can use `window.location.toString()`, `String(window.location)`, or `window.location.href` to get a string for it if you like, or use any of [its various properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties) to check specifics. From the link, given example url `http://www.example.com:80/search?q=devmo#test`:

- **`hash`**: The part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol. You can listen for the hashchange event to get notified of changes to the hash in supporting browsers.
  Example: `#test`
- **`host`**: The host name and port number.
  Example: `www.example.com:80`
- **`hostname`**: The host name (without the port number).
  Example: `www.example.com`
- **`href`**: The entire URL.
  Example: `http://www.example.com:80/search?q=devmo#test`
- **`pathname`**: The path (relative to the host).
  Example: `/search`
- **`port`**: The port number of the URL.
  Example: `80`
- **`protocol`**: The protocol of the URL.
  Example: `http:`
- **`search`**: The part of the URL that follows the ? symbol, including the ? symbol.
  Example: `?q=devmo`

For instance, for your quoted example, you might check `window.location.hostname === "localhost"`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) is a [`Location object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Location_object).

For instance, [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties) will give you the entire URL.

```
var url = window.location.href;
alert(url.indexOf("domain"));
```

But this kind of check is bound to trigger false-positives. You are better using [`window.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties) property which holds the host name part.

```
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
alert(hostname === "my.domain.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make this work:

```
(window.location.href).indexOf("localhost") > -1)
```

I actually use this for my projects as conditionals and it works just fine.

Comment: So weird mine wasn't working without parenthesis around `window.location.href` but adding that works fine! WEIRD