# How to transfer values from one page to another

Tags: jquery, joomla, local-storage

In a joomla site I'm working on, I have a page offering a choice of enrolling in one of several English language programs. The user selects by clicking on the button of choice which is linked to a registration page for the selected program. The html for the links is:

```
<a href="/index.php/register" id="Starting English" class="enrol_btn">Enrol/ลงทะเบียน</a>        
    .....
<a href="/index.php/register" id="Senior School" class="enrol_btn">Enrol/ลงทะเบียน</a>  and so on
```

I want to save the id value so that it can be inserted in the corresponding registration page when that is displayed. As a first step, I've used localStorage with jQuery to save the required id value, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  localStorage.prog = jQuery('a.enrol_btn').attr('id');
+`enter code here`  alert(localStorage.prog);
});
```

This doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Firebug shows that the js file containing this code is being loaded. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set a value to localstorage (which is ID), so that it can be accessed on the same domain but on a different page. You have to do something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('id', jQuery('a.enrol_btn').attr('id'))
```

And later on, get the item using:

```
localStorage.getItem('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you that you have an incorrect value set in the IDs of your anchors, ***as i can see spaces in it and that is absolutely invalid***.

Better to use `_` underscore to fill the space:

```
<a href="/index.php/register" id="Starting_English" class="enrol_btn">Enrol/ลงทะเบียน</a>
   .....<!--check this--------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^up and dowwn-->
<a href="/index.php/register" id="Senior_School" class="enrol_btn">Enrol/ลงทะเบียน</a>
```

You need to use `if/else` conditions at page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var ls = window.localStorage;
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('register') != 0){
      var reg = ls.getItem('registerPage');
      console.log(reg);
  }

  // but you need to make sure you add an obj in the localStorage when you click the link
  $('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ls.setItem('registerPage', this.id); // set the id to localstorage here
     window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');   
  });

});
```

<sub>[NOTE: Ids cannot have "space" separated values.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sub>

Comment: I've corrected the ids :) and replaced the code in the js file with the above code but it is not working. The joomla aliases of the two pages are "enrolment" and "register". Is "registerPage" correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669472/window-location-indexof-not-working-in-javascript

Comment: I've checked out "window.location.indexOf" and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669472/window-location-indexof-not-working-in-javascript   says "window.location is an object, not a string, and so it doesn't have an indexOf function". Any comments?

Comment: Ohh! Yes you need to change `window.location. href.index of()`.

Comment: the console does not return the value of reg.