# document.location.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof, typeerror

I'm using the app HotJar on a specific website of mine.
Now this app records sessions (full recording with mouse movement and everything).
There's an option to "auto-tag" recordings so that some recordings can be found in my library by searching for the specific tag.

I wrote a little script that should tag visits from a specific source.
It looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.indexOf('?utm_source=Bing')  > -1 ) {
        hj('tagRecording', ['Bing_source']);
    }
    if (document.location.indexOf('?gclid=') > -1 ) {
        hj('tagRecording', ['AdWords_source']);
    }
    if (document.location.indexOf('?utm_source=YouTube') > -1 ) {
        hj('tagRecording', ['YouTube_source']);
    }
    if (document.location.indexOf('?u=') > -1 ) {
        hj('tagRecordings', ['Mailchimp_source'])
    }
});
</script>
```

The thing is, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.location.indexOf is not a function
```

I might forgetting something but when searching on stackoverflow this function came up to be a working function.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Go through this Answerfor full explanation 


http://stackoverflow.com/a/13669486/5336818

Answer (score 6):

`indexOf` is a method you find on strings. `location` is not a string.

`location.toString()` is a string and `location.href` is a string.

You probably want to be looking at `location.query` since you are just playing with the query string.

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment.
So     location.href     would be the one to use here?

Comment: why won't you try first then ask? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 document.location.href.indexOf
```

The explanation is because `document.location` is an object, not an string, and where you find the string with the url is in `document.location.href`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!